# I get an Apache Test page in a secondary domain after cloning a server with Plesk

Tags: apache, centos, subdomain, virtualhost, plesk

I had a properly set Centos 6.6 / Apache server with some virtual hosts. I used Plesk to configure it mostly because I am a newby. The main domain was xxdomain.com and we had 2 test websites in test1.xxdomain.com and test2.xxdomain.com everything worked perfectly..

After the migration to the new server, the main website works fine, but now test1.xxdomain.com and the other will not work. I get an Apache Test Page saying "You may now add content to the directory /var/www/html/. Note that until you do so, people visiting your website will see this page and not your content. To prevent this page from ever being used, follow the instructions in the file /etc/httpd/conf.d/welcome.conf.", but the Document Root is setup some where else, plus I also tried copying the files there just in case.

I tried all the solutions here: http://kb.odin.com/en/135 and more, but I am unable to get any result...

-Even when pointing directly to a file, I get a 404 error.. 
-reconfiguring all domains via ssh worked, but when I try the process with the actual test1.xxdomain.com I get "syntax error near unexpected token 'newline'" error. 
-I left just an index.html file with no .htaccess in the Documentroot folder

Answer (score 0):

Check that

- your domain  test2.xxdomain.com is resolving to IP address of Plesk server
- main apache config (httpd.conf) includes conf files generated by plesk. You can do it with command `apachectl -S`
- configs of yuor site presents in `apachectl -S` output

Here the piece of my configs where you can see plesk's webmails entries and my domain "cos66.local":

```
# apachectl -S
VirtualHost configuration:
192.168.0.103:7080     is a NameVirtualHost
         default server default (/etc/httpd/conf/plesk.conf.d/server.conf:70)
         port 7080 namevhost default (/etc/httpd/conf/plesk.conf.d/server.conf:70)
         port 7080 namevhost lists (/etc/httpd/conf/plesk.conf.d/server.conf:142)
                 wild alias lists.*
         port 7080 namevhost horde.webmail (/etc/httpd/conf/plesk.conf.d/horde.conf:9)
                 wild alias horde.webmail.*
         port 7080 namevhost roundcube.webmail (/etc/httpd/conf/plesk.conf.d/roundcube.conf:9)
                 alias webmail.cos66.local
                 wild alias roundcube.webmail.*
         port 7080 namevhost cos66.local (/etc/httpd/conf/plesk.conf.d/vhosts/cos66.local.conf:130)
                 alias www.cos66.local
                 alias ipv4.cos66.local
```

this virtual hosts uses port 7080 because I have enabled nginx integration.